# Phone Factory Reset without carrier apps

Tags: samsung, factory-reset

I am trying to reset my phone (Samsung Galaxy X Cover 3) to factory defaults, using "Settings->Backup and Reset->Factory data reset".

However, there is a step that the carrieer (Orange) has added, it installs several applications (Games, TV, Voicemail, etc) during the first boot.

A black screen without any botton appears and say "installing applications", when the installation is finished the android welcome screen appears.

Is there a way to avoid this step so that no Orange applications are installed ?

(I have tried to interrupt it, restarting the phone during the app installation step, but it is re-run after the reboot).

Comment: Change your firmware :) You might be able to flash a non-carrier-specific rom from [sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to skip the "Installing Applications" screen.

However, you can disable these applications in Settings. If you have root access you can also uninstall them completely.

You can also change the firmware to a non carrier one with Odin. Be careful, because this can brick your device if not done correctly.

Firmwares can be downloaded on [Sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares). (An official firmware will not void warranty)